# DISTINCT Select on comma separated values MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, recursive-query, unnest

Currently I have this table `yeast_module` which  has this field `beer_style`

Which currently, every single row in the `yeast_module` has this `beer_style` data

```
American Amber,American Brown Ale,American India Pale Ale,American Pale Ale,American Porter,American Stout,Barleywine Ale,Belgian Dark Strong Ale,Belgian Table Bier,Belgian Wit,Blonde Ale,Cream Ale,Dusseldorf Altbier,English Brown Ale,English India Pale A
```

Now, I wondering if I can split it and select it distinctly.

I'm playing around on this command

`SELECT DISTINCT beer_style FROM yeast_module`

My expected output is

```
  American Amber,
  American Brown Ale,
  So on..
```

Here's the sample data I have
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The way you store your data makes this kind of task tedious (and inherently inefficient). Storing csv lists in a table column is a typical SQL antipattern, that should almost always be avoided.

Instead, you should have a separate table to represent the one-to-many relationship between yeast modules and beer styles, with each tuple of values on a separate row.

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use a recursive query to unnest the string to rows:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select 
        substring(beer_style, 1, locate(',', concat(beer_style, ',')) - 1) parsed,
        substring(concat(beer_style, ','), locate(',', concat(beer_style, ',')) + 1) remaining
    from mytable
    union all
    select 
        substring(remaining, 1, locate(',', remaining) - 1),
        substring(remaining, locate(',', remaining) + 1)
    from cte
    where locate(',', remaining) > 0
)
select parsed from cte
```

Recommended reading: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/10676716)

Comment: As of now, I'm trying to get it as distinct so I can get all the list of `beer_style` and make a  table for list of `beer_style` to have its own primary key and assign it on `yeast_module` accordingly to make the query easier thanks for your answer

Comment: @RaeIan: just the same query, with `select distinct parsed from cte`.